# Receiving response from facebook login

Tags: facebook, flash-cs5

I am writing a flash app in AS3. I am using the com.facebook.graph library to get the login from my app to work.

If the user is not signed into facebook, a popup appears asking them to enter their username and password like it should. however the issue is that it doesnt seem to be returning to the callback function.

The JS code used to connect looks like this:

```
function redirect() {
            var params = window.location.toString().slice(window.location.toString().indexOf('?'));
            top.location = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=myappID&scope=publish_stream&redirect_uri=http://mydomain.com.au/play.php?'+params;
        }
```

and the AS code looks like this:

```
Facebook.init('myappID', handleLogin);    
function onLoginButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    if (Facebook.getSession()==null ||
        Facebook.getSession().uid  == null) 
    {
        Facebook.login(handleLogin);
    } 
    else{

        handleLogin();
    }

}

function handleLogin(response:Object, fail:Object):void 
{
    if (response == null) 
    {   
        ExternalInterface.call('redirect');
        return;
    }

    postToFB();
}


    function handleUploadComplete(response:Object, fail:Object):void {
    //call back from posting
        }
  function postToFB() {
    messageText.text =  'done';

   }
```

If the user is already logged in , then it runs the posttoFB function correctly, however, if they are not  and it goes through the login procedure, it does not run the function. It seems to just not run the callback function upon completion of the signin process.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

yhou might want to take a look at this page:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/articles/flex_fbgraph_pt4.html